# opengl initialization problem with glew and glfw

Tags: c++, opengl, libraries, glfw, glew

I'm starting to learn the OpenGL stuff, but unfortunately, I can't make the initialization right.
I've added the glfw and glew libraries and these functions give me a strange error,
how can I make it work?

***The code:***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(void)
{
GLFWwindow* window;

/* Initialize the library */
if (!glfwInit())
{
    std::cout << "GLFW initialization failed.\n";
    return -1;
}
if (glewInit()!=GLEW_OK)
{
    std::cout << "GLEW initialization failed.\n";
    return -1;
}
window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);

if (!window)
{
    glfwTerminate();
    std::cout << "Wiondow failed.\n";
    return -1;
}

/* Make the window's context current */
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
/* Loop until the user closes the window */
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    /* Render here */
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    /* Swap front and back buffers */
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);

    /* Poll for and process events */
    glfwPollEvents();
}


glfwTerminate();
return 0;
}
```

***The errors:***
[image: THE ERROS DISPLAYED]

Comment: Do you use a static or dynamic library (dll)? In case of a static library you've to set the preprocessor definition `GLEW_STATIC`.

Comment: Thanks, you are the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To link the [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) library correctly, proper preprocessor definitions have to be set. See [GLEW - Installation](http://glew.sourceforge.net/install.html):

> [...] On Windows, you also need to define the `GLEW_STATIC` preprocessor token when building a static library or executable, and the `GLEW_BUILD` preprocessor token when building a dll [...]